# Derive user control from custom user control base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to create a user control `DerivedUserControl.ascx` that derives form another user control `BaseUserControl.ascx`. The base user control derives from `System.Web.UI.UserControl` as required. These user controls are defined in different folders. Because I'm using a Visual Studio 2010 Web Site project (I'm not able to switch to Web Application project), these user controls are not defined inside a namespace.

My problem is that when I try to compile the project the base class of the derived user control cannot be resolved (obviously because the compiler doesn't know what .ascx file defines the base class). Is there a way resolve this issue?

I tried everything I could imagine, without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**BaseUserControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="BaseUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="BaseUserControl" %>
```

**BaseUserControl.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class BaseUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**DerivedUserControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DerivedUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="DerivedUserControl"  %>
```

**DerivedUserControl.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class DerivedUserControl : BaseUserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**Error**

```
The type or namespace name 'BaseUserControl' could not be found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ASP.NET Web Site (as apposed to a Web Project) you need to add [`<@Reference>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w70c655a.aspx) element to your DerivedUserControl.ascx.

From MSDN it...

> Indicates that another user control, page source file, or arbitrary
>   file located at some virtual path should be dynamically compiled and
>   linked against the current ASP.NET file (Web page, user control, or
>   master page) in which this directive is declared.

`<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/FolderName1/BaseUserControl.ascx" %>`

Once you've done that you can reference it like so

```
public partial class DerivedUserControl : ASP.foldername1.baseusercontrol_ascx
```

Where FolderName1 is the folder your BaseUserControl is in.

Comment: Wow, these seems to work using `ASP.base_baseusercontrol_ascx`.

Comment: I take it `base` is the name of the folder that BaseUserControl.ascx lives in.

Answer (score 1):

Create a regular class/.cs for your base class called `BaseUserControl.cs`:

```
public class BaseUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That would be a nice solution. Unfortunately I can't modify the base class because it's part of a CMS.

Comment: That is a technically sound fix under different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the DerivedUserControl.ascx does not have access to the DLL that contains the BaseUserControl. Make sure that you add a reference to the dll and have copy local = true.

Comment: I use a Web Site Project so I don't get a compiled assembly (dll) i could reference.

Comment: Try putting the path in the Inherits, so that it can find the code that is not in the same directoty

Comment: In a *WebSite* project assemblies are dynamically generated

Answer (score 0):

This does not compile:

```
namespace MyBase
{
    public class BaseUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    { }
}
public class DerivedUserControl : BaseUserControl
{ }
```

This does compile:

```
namespace MyBase
{
    public class BaseUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    { }
}
public class DerivedUserControl :MyBase.BaseUserControl
{ }
```

So pretty much add the name of the namespace + dot + the name of your base class.
Good luck!

Comment: There are no namespaces set using Web Site Projects by default.