# How to inherit a UserControl from another UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, user-controls, nullreferenceexception

Is it possible to inherit a User control from another user control?

The thing I'm trying to achieve is a user control inheriting from another user control. So I have baseusercontrol.ascx, and this just has text "Stuff". Then I have another user control, childusercontrol.ascx inheriting off of baseusercontrol.ascx. If I don't change anything in childusercontrol.ascx, I would expect the baseusercontrol.ascx text to display of "Stuff".

And also I should be able to extend the base user control functionalities in derived one.

I have also tried something like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020335/derive-user-control-from-custom-user-control-base-class), but its not enough in my case.

Now my childusercontrol.ascx looks lie below

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="childusercontrol.ascx.cs" Inherits="test_childusercontrol" %>
<%@ Register src="baseusercontrol.ascx" tagname="baseusercontrol" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

childusercontrol.ascx.cs as below

```
public partial class test_childusercontrol : baseusercontrol
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }   
}
```

When I browse this page Im getting error as

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description : An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any clue?

Comment: Can you share code from the baseusercontrol.ascx? Your error says you have a null reference at a specific line number. I suspect you have a null reference. o_O

Comment: You'll want to look at the stack trace, just like the exception message tells you to. Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Also, no, user controls are not meant to be inherited. The best you can do is to create base classes inheriting `UserControl`, but not containing any markup (no .ascx file).

Answer (score 5):

I have tested this situation for myself. Actually **you can not inherit** from a base class that is a `UserControl` with it's own `ASCX` code.

What you can do however, is **implementing some basic functionality** in a (possibly abstract) base class (without `ASCX`) like this:

```
public class BaseClass:UserControl
{
    public String BaseGreeting { get { return "Welcomebase!"; }}
}
```

And then use the methods and properties of this base class in concrete `UserControl` classes that have their own `ASCX` file.

```
public partial class childusercontrol : BaseClass
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Greeting = base.BaseGreeting; //As initial value
    }
    public String Greeting
    {
        get { return LabelGreeting.Text; }
        set { LabelGreeting.Text = value; }
    }
}
```